# In R, frequency analysis of a single row in a contingency table

Tags: r

How can I get a frequency distribution and percentage of `where 4 or more` for each row of this contingency table?

```
> table(People$Gender, People$BooksOwned)

       -1   3   4   5   6   8  10  12
    0   0   1 125   7 170  73   1   2
    1   2   0  11   0  20  14   1   1
```

I've no idea how to call functions on individual rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was [easy](https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/ca.html):

```
> gender_books <- table(People$Gender, People$BooksOwned)
> prop.table(gender_books, 1) # row percentages, column is 2

0 0.000000000 0.002638522 0.329815303 0.018469657 0.448548813 0.192612137 0.002638522 0.005277045
1 0.040816327 0.000000000 0.224489796 0.000000000 0.408163265 0.285714286 0.020408163 0.020408163

gender_books_percents <- prop.table(gender_books, 1)
rowSums(gender_books_percents[,c('4', '6', '8', '10', '12')], na.rm=TRUE)

0         1 
0.6490765 0.7346939
```